# How to put text in the middle of div and form?

Tags: html, css

I want to ask, how can I put text (`<h3>` on picture) in the middle of div and form? I want to have same space between edges of these two objects.

Source is on the picture below.

[image]

Thank you for your advices and have a nice day.

Comment: Use CSS property `text-align: center`

Comment: Please include on the question your actual code HTML and CSS not that as a picture

Comment: M.Black, welcome to stack overflow. We need to see your HTML structure and the CSS you've tried so far. Also, you you want the h3 between the left div and the form, but you also have a "div group" - what should happen with that?

Comment: not sure but remove float:left from menu  div or post your code also try margin:0; on h3

Comment: OP stated in a comment on a deleted answer that `text-align:center` does _not_ give the desired result. We don't even know what the desired result is, because "in the middle" is vague.  Unfortunately it is _impossible_ to intelligently answer this question in its current state; there is no HTML in the question and only an image of _partial_ CSS.